# Round the corners of outline property CSS

Tags: html, css, outline

I have this element with this style added:

```
.checkout-step.current .number {
  background-color: #d26d51;
  outline: 1px solid #d26d51;
  outline-offset: 4px;
}
```

[image]

But I not want square corners in the outline, I want round the corners, like this example:
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: use `:after` instead of `outline`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My approach is as follows. Please check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6QUhf/141/).
I have added following HTML.

```
<a href="#">2</a>
```

I have added following css.

```
a {
  background: #999;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use border-radius property to do this.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: You can't use `border-radius` on the `outline` property.

Answer (score -1):

**use this code **
outline  we cant use radius property Instead of outline make as border and radius so i changed code like this Try This .

> Html

```
<div class="usecode"><div class=".checkout-step.current .number">2</div></div>
```

> css

```
    .checkout-step.current .number {
      background-color: #d26d51;
     margin:15px;

      }

.usecode
 {
 border:1px solid #d26d51;
border-radius:25px !important;
 }
```